# Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException - no close()

Tags: java, exception, nosuchelementexception

I have this problem I need to resolve in the next 8 hours (max), I read a lot of posts with similar problems, but they always call to remove close(). I don't have it and my problem still exists.

```
package Kolokwium;
import java.io.*;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Group{
    int availableseats;
    int occupiedseats= 0;

    public Group()  {
        try (
               PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("C:\\Users\\Galaxis\\Desktop\\lesson_name.txt");
               BufferedReader reader  = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            ) {
                System.out.println("Lesson name: ");
                String lesson_nameu = reader.readLine();
                System.out.println("Available seats:");
                String seats= reader.readLine();
                writer.println(lesson_name + " " + seats);
                availableseats= Integer.parseInt(seats);
        }
        catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public void add_student() {
        if (occupiedseats < availableseats) {
            try (
              PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("C:\\Users\\Galaxis\\Desktop\\lesson_name.txt");
              BufferedReader reader  = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            ) {
                System.out.println("Write student's data: ");
                String data = reader.readLine();
                occupiedseats += 1;
                writer.println(data);
            }
            catch (IOException ex) {
                ex.printStackTrace();
            }
        } else {
            System.out.println("No available seats!");
        }
    }

    public void show_list() {
        File path = new File("C:\\Users\\Galaxis\\Desktop\\lesson_name.txt");
        String[] list;
        list = path.list();
        for (int i=0; i < list.length; i++)
        System.out.println(list[i]);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Group group = new Group();
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("MENU " + "1. Add student. " + "2. Show list. ");
        int ichoice = in.nextInt();

        if(ichoice  == 1) {
            group.add_student();
        }
        else if(ichoice == 2) {
            group.show_list();
        }
        else {System.out.println("Wrong choice!");}
    }
}
```

Eclipse give me this message when it comes to "int ichoice = in.nextInt();"

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
    at Kolokwium.Grupa.main(Grupa.java:76)
```

Comment: Can you please translate all the variable  and method names to English? The code is almost unreadable like this. Even if you are not a native speaker, it is good industry practice to program in English only.

Comment: A couple of things that will help you get an answer: 1) indent your code correctly, it's difficult to read as it is, 2) It would really help if you specify exactly where the exception is thrown from

Comment: I don't see why a `NoSuchElementException` would have any association with a `close()` method.  In any case, the stack trace for your exception would be pretty informative about the problem.

Comment: @JanHenke I disagree about english being a good industry practise, but I agree it makes code easier to read for anybody else...

Comment: Can you add the stack trace? It is usually very valuable information...

Comment: It seems that your file data ends before expected. I agree with the other comments: English, indentation, where is being thrown the exception, ...

Comment: It's very poor form for a constructor to do I/O.  Also, it is rarely sufficient to handle exceptions by printing a message and otherwise continuing as if nothing happened.

Answer (score 3):

```
public void pokaz_liste() {
        File path = new File("C:\\Users\\Galaxis\\Desktop\\nazwa_przedmiotu.txt");
        String[] list;
        list = path.list();
        for (int i=0; i < list.length; i++)
        System.out.println(list[i]);
    }
```

You are trying to get a list of files from a File. Javadoc states that, if the file instance does not point to a directory, it will return null.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#list()

And for God's sake, flush and close your streams!

For your exception: The scanner is exhausted. Try this

```
public Group()  {
        try (
               PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter("C:\\Users\\Galaxis\\Desktop\\lesson_name.txt");
            ) {
                BufferedReader reader  = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
                System.out.println("Lesson name: ");
                String lesson_nameu = reader.readLine();
                System.out.println("Available seats:");
                String seats= reader.readLine();
                writer.println(lesson_name + " " + seats);
                seats2 = Integer.parseInt(seats);
        }
        catch (IOException ex) {
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Comment: It's not the problem, even when I delete pokaz_liste from the program, it shows me the same problem. I forgot to write exactly what Eclipse tell me:

    Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException

 at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.Scanner.next(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Unknown Source)
 at Kolokwium.Grupa.main(Grupa.java:76)

Comment: @Galaxis post the stacktrace please

Comment: Changing to 
"in.nextLine();
int iwybor = in.nextInt();"
changes my problem to:

     No line found at java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Unknown Source)

Comment: @Galaxis remove that line. And, in `Group` constructor, where is `seats2` declared?

Comment: No, I can't. And also, I had a little mistake - seats2 should be availableseats.
If I put this in the Group, I would need to put here also declaration of the scanner, then I can't use "ichoice" in the main...

Comment: @Galaxis if you comment out the `Group group = new Group();` line, do you still get that error? And are you testing it from command line or from eclipse console?

Comment: There is a huge problem that I can't change the code too much - I can only "correct".

Comment: Commenting this will cause not creating any group, so I can't use group.add_student etc. because there is no group.
From Eclipse.

Comment: @Galaxis the point of commenting out lines is just to isolate the source of the error (the exception might be thrown at `nextInt()`, but might be caused by another problem) in order to find a fix. After fixed, you can put back the original code

Comment: If I comment Group group = new Group();, group.add_student(); and group.show_list(); then it don't show me any error

Comment: @Galaxis Ok, I have made some test and come up with a fix. I edited my post, at the bottom, can you make the change I show? (Basically, take the reader declaration out of the `try` initialization block). Because the try block is automatically closing it

Comment: Now it lets me to choose an option, I chose 1 - add_student, with in.nextLine(); in the main it doesn't go to "Write student's data", just hanging in the console, when I write something and click enter it shows the same error as always. Without in.nextLine(); in the main it shows me "Write student's data:", but when I write something, it doesn't do anything. Also, there is a problem with writers, I check the file twice - before and after menu appears. Before there is lesson_name + availableseats, but after I choose 1 - add_student, file is empty.

Comment: @Galaxis 1 - you can remove already `in.nextLine()`. 2 - For the writer, initialize it like `new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream("/you/files/here.txt", true));` 3 - After writing the data, flush the writer stream.

Comment: PrintWriter writer = new PrintWriter(new FileOutputStream("C:\\Users\\Galaxis\\Desktop\\lesson_name.txt", true))

       and      writer.flush(); after every writer.println
Still the same problem.

Comment: @Galaxis one more thing, can you put `reader.nextLine();` before `String data = reader.readLine();` in the function `add_student()` ?

Comment: "The method readLine is undefined for the type BufferedReader"
But add_student works good for now, I think. It adds first data in file withour replacing previous, I just didn't create a loop for adding data multiple times. But when I try to run show_list:
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
 at Kolokwium.Group.show_list(Group.java:68)
 at Kolokwium.Group.main(Group.java:86)

Comment: @Galaxis the nullpointerexception is because you are pointing to a file, not to a directory

Comment: Oh, I see. I changed it, now it works. Thank you for SO much help and patience! :)

Comment: @Galaxis, no worries, we are here to help :)